# Python: Passing in a tuple as an argument in a function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am creating new columns for a `Pandas DataFrame` using `np.select(condition, choices)`. I would like to modularize my code into a function to do so, and my cumbersome way is as follows:

```
def selection(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    conditions: Optional[List] = None,
    choices: Optional[List] = None,
    column_names: Optional[List] = None,
):
    if conditions is not None:  # if its none, then don't run this, implies choices and column names are none too
        for condition, choice, col_name in zip(conditions, choices, column_names):
            df[col_name] = np.select(condition, choice, default=" ")
    return df
```

To run this function, I merely do this:

```
conditions = [...]
choices = [...]
column_names = [...]
my_tuple = (conditions, choices, column_names)
df = selection(df, *my_tuple)
```

I want to improve my coding skills, and I feel this way is suboptimal, in particular, I feel my arguments involving `conditions, choices, column_names` can be a tuple to be passed in as an argument. I welcome any suggestion on improving this code.

Comment: Why the tuple? Why not just `df = selection(df, coditions, choices, column_names)`?

Comment: I wanted to make the function more compact, or you can say more elegant. I’m just trying to adopt better practices, but as someone who has no background in CS, self learning is always quite tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to pass them as a tuple, yes, you can:

```
def selection(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    cond_choice_col: Optional[Tuple] = None
):
    if cond_choice_col is not None:  # if its none, then don't run this, implies choices and column names are none too

        # unpack the tuple here
        for condition, choice, col_name in zip(*cond_choice_col):
            df[col_name] = np.select(condition, choice, default=" ")
    return df

conditions = [...]
choices = [...]
column_names = [...]
my_tuple = (conditions, choices, column_names)

df = selection(df, cond_choice_col=my_tuple)
```

But honestly, I do think your function is a lot user friendly than the above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there anything else that looks bad in the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [53]: def foo(df, conditions=None, choices=None):
    ...:     print(df, conditions, choices)
    ...: 
In [54]: foo('df')
df None None
```

With keywords, you can supply arguments with a dict:

```
In [55]: adict={'conditions':[1,2,3], 'choices':['yes','no']}
In [56]: foo('df', **adict)
df [1, 2, 3] ['yes', 'no']
```

or a tuple of values:

```
In [57]: foo('df', *adict.values())
df [1, 2, 3] ['yes', 'no']
```

More on argument syntax and unpacking:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions